# Should a class have string fields for values from SQL JOIN from dictionary tables

Tags: c#, sql

I have a class (code below) that I use to save to and read from db. Everything works fine but when it comes to finally print some object information taken from dictionary tables I really don't know where to put them. (Active Record).

Code of class:

```
class Object
{
   public int id;
   public int size;
   public int color;
   public int author;

   public Object(int id, int size, int color, int author)
   {
      this.id = id;
      this.size = size;
      this.color = color;
      this.author = author;
   }

   // add, update, delete methods
}
```

So for above class the SQL:

> select id, size, color, author from object;

Should I add string fields into this class to look like this:

```
class Object
{
   public int id;
   public int size;
   public int color;
   public int author;

   // String fields for dictionary
   public string sizeString;
   public string colorString;
   public string authorString;
   //

   // Nr 1
   public Object(int id, int size, int color, int author)
   {
      this.id = id;
      this.size = size;
      this.color = color;
      this.author = author;
   }

   // Nr 2
   public Object(int id, string size, string color, string author)
   {
      this.id = id;
      this.size = sizeString;
      this.color = colorString;
      this.author = authorString;
   }

   // add, update, delete methods
}
```

SQL:

```
select o.id, s.size, c.color, a.name
from object o
join sizes s on o.size = s.id
join colors c on o.color = c.id
join authors a on o.author = a.id
```

If this approach is correct then should my new constructor (Nr 2) look like above I mean should I left the int fields empty or always get all data from db:

```
public Object(int id, int size, int color, int author,
              string sizeString, string colorString,
              string authorString)
   {
      this.id = id;

      this.size = size;
      this.color = color;
      this.author = author;

      this.sizeString = sizeString;
      this.colorString = colorString;
      this.authorString = authorString;
   }
```

SQL:

```
select o.id, o.size, o.color, o.author,
       s.size as sizeS, c.color as colorS, a.name as authorS
from object o
join sizes s on o.size = s.id
join colors c on o.color = c.id
join authors a on o.author = a.id
```

If whole idea of adding addtional string fields is bad please steer me in a right direction. Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi user2832281, the correct answer to your design question depends a lot on how you want to use the classes going forward. Do you just need to print them out or will you need to do full CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) on them?

Comment: Hi @earthling42, I just need to print them out, for CRUD I don't really need them.

Comment: You can print integers to strings by calling ToString(). Or if you are just doing something like Console.WriteLine() you can just pass the integer in and it will automatically make it a string. Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @KevinCrowell, no it's not what I am looking for. What I need to know is if I want to get data from dictionary table eg. colors, so color with ID=1, has Name=Red when I use join should I store this fetched color to my Object class or use another class that will contains string fields for dictionary data.

Comment: It sounds like you might be wanting to map your database tables to object classes. Have you looked into using an ORM? Such as: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put in items which resolve the ids to their corresponding values such as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IColorResolver colors = new ColorResolver();
            IObject demoObject1 = new Object(1, 1, 1, 1, colors);
            IObject demoObject2 = new Object(2, 3, 3, 3, colors);
            Console.WriteLine("demoObject1: {0}", demoObject1.Color.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("demoObject2: {0}", demoObject2.Color.Name);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public interface IObject
    {
        int Id { get; }
        ISize Size { get; set; }
        IColor Color { get; set; }
        IAuthor Author { get; set; }
    }

    public class Object: IObject
    {
        bool isDirty = false;

        readonly int id;
        int size;
        int color;
        int author;

        IColorResolver colors;

        public int Id { get { return this.id; } }
        public ISize Size { get; set; } //this would implement code like Color's
        public IAuthor Author { get; set; }//this would implement code like Color's
        public IColor Color
        {
            get { return colors.GetColor(color); }
            set
            {
                if (!this.color.Equals(value.Id))
                {
                    this.color = value.Id;
                    this.isDirty = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public Object(int id, int size, int color, int author, IColorResolver colorResolver)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.size = size;
            this.color = color;
            this.author = author;

            this.colors = colorResolver;
        }

        // add, update, delete methods
    }

    public interface ILookupValue
    {
        int Id { get; }
        string Name { get; /*set;*/ } //no set since this is a lookup so we don't want to amend it
    }
    public interface IColor: ILookupValue
    {
        IColorResolver GetResolver();
    }
    public interface IAuthor : ILookupValue { /* ... */ }
    public interface ISize : ILookupValue { /* ... */ }

    public class Color : IColor
    {
        int id;
        string name;
        IColorResolver colors;
        public int Id { get { return this.id; } }
        public string Name { get { return this.name; } }
        public Color(int id, string name, IColorResolver colors)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.colors = colors;
            this.colors.AddColor(this);
        }
        public IColorResolver GetResolver() { return this.colors; }
    }

    public interface IColorResolver
    {
        IColor GetColor(int id);
        void AddColor(IColor color);
    }

    public class ColorResolver : IColorResolver
    {
        IDictionary<int, IColor> colors = new Dictionary<int, IColor>();
        public ColorResolver()
        {
            /*
             in reality you'd probably pass a data layer object through 
             the constructor to fetch these values from your database 
            */
            new Color(1, "Red", this);
            new Color(2, "Green", this);
            new Color(3, "Blue", this);
        }
        public void AddColor(IColor color)
        {
            this.colors.Add(color.Id, color);
        }
        public IColor GetColor(int id)
        {
            IColor result;
            this.colors.TryGetValue(id, out result); //you could throw an exception here if not found
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

The reason for the huge amount of interfaces in the above code is this makes testing simpler; i.e. I can create Mock objects for any of my objects and pass them in instead of my real objects.